# Site is not registering my last daily vote

Tags: bug, voting

I am unable to continue upvoting questions as I have reached my daily voting limit of 40 votes(which is expected). When I try to upvote a question, I get a red pop-up message that indicates that I have reached my daily limit(this is also expected behavior).

However, in my dropdown profile, the site only shows that I have voted 39 times today. Looking at my profile, I can see that I have 40 votes recorded since the last daily rollover @0:00 UTC. This would also prevent me from getting the vox populi badge.

Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you already hit the vote limit because of voting for answers, and not having for 10 questions yet.

Looking at the [FAQ](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) for reference:

> A maximum of 40 votes can be cast per user per day, however, to reach
>   the maximum you must vote on at least 10 questions.

So it's limited to voting on 30 answers only, with 10 extra votes available for questions.
Note, for example, once you got a message "5 votes left", it will count down even if you now vote only on questions and you still think you have those 10 question votes. The system doesn't lie, so you vote on a question and will get the message "4 votes left". This way you can end with 39 votes only.

I tested today and got the [Vox Populi](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/71/vox-populi) badge for voting 40 times a day. Now 5 members have this badge. So it's possible and currently working.

So, to reach the limit of 40, I suggest to vote earlier on questions.

Comment: That's...interesting. I hadn't run across that before. Thanks.